# Android 2.2 black screen when AsyncTask cancelled during double splash screen

Tags: android, eclipse, asynchronous, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I have a 2 part splash screen that I've been trying to get to work on Android 2.2 (eclipse emulator) Everything works in 2.3 emulator. In 2.2 it works more often than not - sometimes goes to black screen - sometimes I need to restart the emulator. If I try to click the screen to cancel the splash and go right to the main activity, it goes to black screen and in the log I see:

```
06-29 12:23:54.474: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=org.test.game/.MainActivity }
06-29 12:23:54.494: W/System.err(278): java.lang.InterruptedException
06-29 12:23:54.504: D/qemud(37): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
06-29 12:23:54.504: D/qemud(37): created client 0x17fe8 listening on fd 15
06-29 12:23:54.504: D/qemud(37): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'sensors'
06-29 12:23:54.504: D/qemud(37): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 11
06-29 12:23:54.514: D/qemud(37): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 11
06-29 12:23:54.524: D/qemud(37): fdhandler_accept_event: accepting on fd 10
06-29 12:23:54.524: D/qemud(37): created client 0x18038 listening on fd 16
06-29 12:23:54.524: D/qemud(37): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 15
06-29 12:23:54.544: W/System.err(278):  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
06-29 12:23:54.554: W/System.err(278):  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1306)
06-29 12:23:54.554: W/System.err(278):  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1286)
06-29 12:23:54.564: W/System.err(278):  at org.test.game.Splash$SplashScreenDelay.doInBackground(Splash.java:121)
06-29 12:23:54.574: W/System.err(278):  at org.test.game.Splash$SplashScreenDelay.doInBackground(Splash.java:1)
06-29 12:23:54.584: W/System.err(278):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-29 12:23:54.594: W/System.err(278):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-29 12:23:54.604: W/System.err(278):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-29 12:23:54.604: W/System.err(278):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
06-29 12:23:54.614: W/System.err(278):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
06-29 12:23:54.624: W/System.err(278):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
06-29 12:24:04.475: W/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-29 12:24:04.484: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44eca1f8 org.test.game/.MainActivity}
06-29 12:24:14.494: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44ebb9b0 org.test.game/.Splash}
```

Inspired by http://webgarbage.de/splash-screen-on-android.html

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    private AsyncTask splashDelay;
    private ImageView ivSplash;
    private int splashCount = 0;
    private int splashTime = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        ivSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVSplash);
        splashDelay = new SplashScreenDelay().execute(splashTime);
    }

    //Touch screen to skip splash
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            splashDelay.cancel(true);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class SplashScreenDelay extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            try {
                int count = 0;
                while (count < params[0]*10) {
                    if(count % 10 == 0) { 
                        Log.v("Splash", "Sleeping... " + count/10); 
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    count++;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new Integer(0);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            if (splashCount == 0) {
                splashCount = 1;
                ivSplash.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash2);
                splashDelay = new SplashScreenDelay().execute(splashTime); 
            }
            else 
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        }

        protected void onCancelled() {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice? What's making the cancelling of the splash give a black screen?
I've read that "launch timeout has expired" error comes when the MainActivity has to wait too long, but if the splash works interrupted (more time) why should it fail when there is a cancel (less time)?

Thanks

Comment: override onStop method of Activity and put splashDelay.cancel() in that. so when ever your activity stop as soon as your splashDelay also.

Comment: Added onStop, same thing still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An async task is not well suited for setting a timer on your splash screen.  A more suitable method would be to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and sendDelayed to delay the splash screen.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is this a truth in general or just for 2.2? I've read so many pages most of them recommend Asynctask.

Comment: AsyncTask is generally used for doing blocking operations on a separate thread.  The task above does no actual work, and is causing instability.  Handlers and messages are used for the process to signal itself.  sendMessageDelayed will accomplish the same as the above async task without overly complicating the activity.

Comment: To expand on this, Thread.sleep() is usually the wrong way to put delays into your app unless they are really tiny. Better to use alarms or delayed messages.

Comment: I have not looked into alarms... is that referring to the AlarmManager class?

Comment: Changed it to use Handler and postDelayed. Now works with 2.2. Can click screen and do not get black screen.